# How to get edit information from TStringGrid

Tags: windows, edit, tstringgrid

I have a TStringGrid application that has a search faclilty. When the user selects Search Again I want to be able to continue the search from where the cursor is within a particular cell.

Edit boxes (i.e. TEdit) have properties SelStart and SelLength that I can use to achieve this, but I can't find anywhere to get this from TStringGrid.

Is it possible to get stuff like this from TStringGrid?

For historical reasons I am developing in Windows98.

I have looked over as much TStringGrid documentation (including properties, methods and events) and not found anything relating to what I want to do.